# Android - Best approach for passing context in adapter (Specifically `RecyclerViewAdapter`)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

I have a `RecyclerView` with its `Adapter` in a `Fragment`. Currently I'm hunting for OOM causes and `Context` leaking might be one of the cause.

There are several approaches I did in getting the context in `Adapter` (Need the `Context` for `SharedPreferences`, `Glide`/`Picasso`, and replacing `Fragments`).

1. Passing the `Context` through the adapter constructor and then set it into global variable inside the adapter :

   `LobbyAdapter lobbyAdapter = new LobbyAdapter(this.getActivity);`
2. Have a global `Context` in the `Adapter` and take the `Context` from `onCreateViewHolder` :

   `context = parent.getContext();`
   This causes problem when I `new` the Adapter using `SwipeRefreshLayout`. But this must be because of the flawed logic I did in the `Fragment`, still tracking this down.
3. Don't make a global `Context` variable, but, get every `Context` from the `View` from every `ViewHolder` related to the `Context`

`Loading an image`

`The key here is using the holder to get the Context ((FriendProfileViewHolder) holder).coverPhoto.getContext()`

```
Glide.with(((FriendProfileViewHolder) holder).coverPhoto.getContext())
.load(utilities.webAddress + profileDataModel.user_cover_image_path)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
.skipMemoryCache(true)
.centerCrop()
.into(((FriendProfileViewHolder) holder).coverPhoto);
```

In this part, due to my lack of experience with `Context`, I'm not sure which view should we get the `Context` if one method is reused by different `Views`
.

Additional question : (This might need new question thread..)

In several `Adapters`, I do an `AsyncTask` to get response from server to change image. And I need `Context` in the `Interface` to do `getPackageName()` to get package of the app, and `getResources()` to access resources.

```
String pictureName = output.image_name_profile;
String packageName = context.getPackageName();

if(!pictureName.equals("default")){
    resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + pictureName, null, packageName);
    image = context.getResources().getDrawable(resId);
        }
```

Maybe I should create a global variable and method to mutate those values?

Answer (score 0):

I've used the first approach that you described in your question, the one for passing Context through a constructor and then set it to global variable for later use. This approach works great for Fragments containing RecyclerViews. Used it for a couple of times and it has never caused a Context leak problem.

I've not used any of the other approaches so will not comment on them.

Comment: Hmm.. So it never had any leak problem for you.. I have an Activity which holds loads of Fragments, if I keep doing `this.getActivity()` on every Fragment to pass the Context, it should be fine then?

Comment: Yes, it will work fine. There won't be any Context leaks.

Comment: This is a different question, so.. How do you manage memory for a `Fragment` which get content, dynamically from the server? Take social media apps for example, I keep getting the contents, and it keep taking up memory space, even after moving to other Fragment..

Comment: Fragments do take up lot of space, especially when they contain RecyclerViews or ListViews inside them. To manage memory efficiently, I used a ViewPager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter. FragmentStatePagerAdapter removes the pages or Fragments that are currently not in use and just save their states so that they can be loaded to the state where the user left them.

Comment: This saves a lot of space as compared to FragmentPAgerAdapter.

Comment: I created a music player app with this approach and even with 7-8 Fragments and overall more than 500 songs to inflate in each RecyclerView, the FragmentStatePAgerAdapter was memory efficient.

Comment: Try using a ViewPager for containing your Fragments inside the Activity and inflate it with FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Comment: Visit the link for more info on the Adapter: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

Comment: I also do that for when opening a friend's profile, but It doesn't release the memory.. Do you always need to nullify an imageview? Because a lot of retained heap was there in my drawables..

Comment: I used WeakReference for referencing images to ImageViews. So, whenever GC (Garbage Collector) needed memory, it cleared them off.

Comment: I use Glide to load images.. It automatically use caching, so it shouldn't be the problem, right??

Comment: Caching improves app performance considerably by reducing the access time required to access or load any file but it doesn't make sure that Garbage Collector can clean as much memory it needs and whenever it needs it. This can only be achieved by dereferencing large memory consuming objects whenever they are not required by the app. This can easily be achieved by WeakReference or any other similar approach. I'll suggest you to use the WeakReference approach along with caching.

Comment: In case, WeakReference approach is not used by Glide, visit the following link for complete guide on how to use WeakReferences: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html